# Is there a reason that scikit-learn only allows access to clf.coef_ with linear svms?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I would like to calculate the primal variables w with a polynomial kernel svm, but to do this i need to compute clf.coef_ * clf.support_vectors_. Access is restricted to .coef_ on all kernel types except for linear - is there a reason for this, and is there another way to derive w in that case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They simply don't exist for kernels that are not linear: The kernel SVM is solved in the dual space, so in general you only have access to the dual coefficients.

In the linear case this can be translated to primal feature space coefficients. In the general case these coefficients would have to live in the feature space spanned by the chosen kernel, which can be infinite dimensional.

Comment: For the specific case of the polynomial kernel, you can actually create this feature space by using a linear kernel on your data preprocessed by `sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures`. Up to some scaling using those should be able to give you the same results. (In this case the feature space is finite dimensional, but it very quickly blows up in dimension with polynomial order)

Comment: Specifically I am interested in computing the margin, which is the reciprocal of the norm of w (right?). Currently I am calculating w with dual_coefs_ * support_vectors_, is that correct, and if not, does it mean anything at all wrt the margin? Thanks for the preproccessing suggestions, that approach makes sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

An answer to the comment on computing the margin:

According to [the wikipedia entry on support vector machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine), the margin width is calculated by `2 / ||w||`. Let us verify some other formulas in that article.

We use two perfectly separable square point clouds in 2D

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

n_samples = 100
neg_samples = rng.rand(n_samples // 2, 2)
pos_samples = rng.rand(n_samples // 2, 2) + np.array([3, 3])

X = np.vstack([neg_samples, pos_samples])
y = np.concatenate([-np.ones(n_samples // 2), np.ones(n_samples // 2)])

from sklearn.svm import SVC
svc = SVC(kernel="linear")

svc.fit(X, y)
```

Observe that

```
svc.dual_coef_ == np.array([0.1999464, -0.1999464])
```

and thus of sum zero. We can tentatively conclude that `svc.dual_coef_` corresponds to `alpha * y` from the wikipedia article.

Let us now calculate the decision vector and margins

```
w = svc.dual_coef_.dot(svc.support_vectors_)
margin = 2 / np.sqrt((w ** 2).sum())

from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances
distances = euclidean_distances(neg_samples, pos_samples)

assert np.abs(margin - distances.min()) < 1e-6
```

We have thus asserted that the margin calculated above corresponds to the minimal distance between the point clouds.